# LocationServices.FusedLocationApi

Tags: java, android

Does fused location api charges money when a request is very much per day it will be for 2 sec ? for one thousand clients

```
 Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(getGoogleApiClient());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard of Google charging for fused location if you are using it for GPS. Other services might charge but if you want to know more check this page out: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/